# How to implement your own cd command in your own shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, cd, pwd

I am working in a mini project: "MY OWN COMMAND INTERPRETER (SHELL)", like the Bash shell or Sh shell. Till now it can execute every predefined commands like ls, ps, pwd, date. Except this I have implemented some other operations like Input Redirection(<), output redirection(>), PIPE (|) features. Along with this i have implemented my own user-commands like pid, ppid, quit, hist.

```
vvdnlt208@vvdnlt208-Vostro-3446:~/project/Vector/sourabh/unix/proj2$ ./my_sh  
<1 SOURABH> ls
 a     cd.c       execute.o  inredir.c  main.o   multiexec.o  my_sh   sh.c                sigign.c  test.c
addhist.c  dir        header.h   inredir.o  Makefile     mypipe.c     outredir.c  showhist.c  sigign.o  tetest.c
addhist.o  execute.c  inredir    main.c     multiexec.c  mypipe.o     outredir.o    showhist.o  test2.c
<2 SOURABH> ps
PID TTY          TIME CMD
6120 pts/10   00:00:01 bash
6510 pts/10   00:00:00 grep
6512 pts/10   00:00:00 grep
6514 pts/10   00:00:00 grep
6516 pts/10   00:00:00 grep
7772 pts/10   00:00:00 my_sh
7774 pts/10   00:00:00 ps
<3 SOURABH> pwd
/home/vvdnlt208/project/Vector/sourabh/unix/proj2
<4 SOURABH> date
Fri Nov 14 16:44:24 IST 2014
<5 SOURABH> 
<6 SOURABH> 
<7 SOURABH> 
<8 SOURABH> hist
1 ls
2 ps
3 pwd
4 date
8 hist
<9 SOURABH> ls >a.txt
<10 SOURABH> pid
7772
<11 SOURABH> ppid
```

But I am facing some difficulty in executing the cd command...

```
<12 SOURABH> cd
cd: No such file or directory
<13 SOURABH> cd dir
cd: No such file or directory
<14 SOURABH>
```

Someone told me to implement it by my own... Please help me in doing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to help without any look on the code...

Comment: So you implemented all the stuff and now you ask how to implement `cd` and you actually show us your try being "executing cd"? That's kind of weird. Is it maybe your homework to implement `cd` and anything else was written by someone else?

Comment: cd is a builtin command, so there is no cd program to run. cd consists of two operations: 1. check that the directory exists. 2. Set OLDPWD to PWD and PWD to the new directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the cd command work in my shell program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3740504/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cd` is not a program, it's a built-in command. The built-in command are directly built into the shell.

To implement `cd`, you basically need to

1. Use `chdir()` to change the current directory
2. Update some environment variables (like Klas Lindback said: `OLDPWD` and `PWD`)

Comment: The check for existence is unnecessary, `chdir` fails in that case. (And it's useless, too, the directory could exist while `stat`ing and be deleted before the `chdir` call.)

Comment: I suggest emphasizing that `cd` cannot be implemented as a program. Similar questions came up a few times during the last weeks and often people aren't aware that a process cannot change its parent's environment.

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to have a look at the `chdir` function in `unistd.h`. This changes the working directory of the current process.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have used chdir() to implement my cd command and it works. Every process has its own PWD(Present Working Directory). A shell is also a process and its default PWD is the PWD of its parent (bash shell where I have executed ./my_sh).